# Querying ElasticSearch document based on particular value without knowing field name

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to query the entire index based on particular text value. I don't have field name to query for. Is it possible to search the documents based on particular text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html). 
You can specify multiple fields. If no field is specified it will search in entire document

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "text"
        }
    }
}
```